# CSS one under another positionning

Tags: html, css

I've got 2 `div`s. The first one should fit the page after loading. And the next one should be under the 1st one after scrolling. How to accomplish that?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="first">

</div>

.first { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

And

```
<div class="second">

</div>

.second {}
```

Which additional properties should they have?

Comment: use position fixed then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
.first {
    min-height:100%;
    background:#f00;
}
.second {
    background:#ff0;
    height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnWxj/

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of the first div to 100%

Comment: "position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;" will give it a width of 100% already.  However, it will appear on top of the other layer due to the absolute positioning.

Comment: Absolute positioning means that the result is fixed. You're going to need something relative to get what you're looking for. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle works, however, there is a space between these divs. I haven't got the faintest idea how to remove that.